# Error when try to deploy salesforce functions

Tags: salesforce-functions

I have created salesforce functions and created compute environment .But it is giving me the below error when i try to deploy my functions

Pushing changes to functions... failed
»   Error: Invalid project.toml - File Not Found: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\Documents\VS
»   CODE\FUNCTIONS4\functions.git\project.toml' Are you in the correct working directory?

Comment: @Julián Duque Can you please help me on this

Comment: I feel there should be a way to change the directory so that it can find correct project.toml but currently I'm stuck here too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I copied one function from one project to another.
When you create a functions its generate the project.toml automaticaly, In my case y lost the file in the copy.
try to generate the function again and merge you code.
I hope its help

Answer (score 0):

This is because you also created a `.git` folder inside your function.

There should only be 1 `.git` folder at `<functionsTrialOrg>` (which I assume is your FUNCTIONS4 org.

**So how to resolve this?**

In your VS Code terminal, navigate to `C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\Documents\VS » CODE\FUNCTIONS4\functions` then type the command below :

> rm -rf .git

to delete that .git folder.

Then navigate back to `C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\Documents\VS » CODE\FUNCTIONS4` and then run

```
sf deploy functions -o <devhubaliasname>
```

You can find the DevHub alias name by `sfdx alias list`